# 2 identical ceiling fans stopped working after reinstalling them

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, fans

I am a professional electrician. I took down 2 ceiling fans and after reinstalling them they were no functioning anymore. Can anyone explain me how is this possible please???

The electricity cables of the 2 ceiling fans were very visible. 1 cable was hanging loose from the ceiling and was only fixed with 2 hooks over a length of 6 meters. It was ugly.

After removing the fans completely, because they were not secured to the ceiling, I put them in the living room a few meters from where I removed them. 
I was extremely careful when I handled them because my friend told me that the man who installed them told her that they are very delicate. I have no experience with fans but I know how they work.

After gluing the cable, to the wooden beams of the ceiling, I reinstalled the fans with great care. First I secured them to the wooden beam so that I could connect the wires when the fan was pending. It made connecting the wires really easy. But before I did that I tested the wiring with my multi-meter. All was well so I connected the cables to the fans.

The end? No! When I turned the switch nothing happened. Both fans did not work!!!

I googled and followed a trouble shooting guide. I had electricity so the wiring is ok. The capacitor was ok. But the there was no movement at all, both fans where broken. My friend asked a professional and he said that the motor is broken.

I am a Belgian living in Spain and I do not understand what the professional is saying. He is asking more than 200€ for the repair. My research said that an motor can cost 100€ or more.

I want to be able to explain this to my friend who is not talking to me because of this.

I also want to make sure that, when I replace the motors, I do not have the same problem again.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: please post a picture of one of the fans

Comment: Include make and model of fans. This way we can tell you which wires are for what. Do the fans have a light kit installed on them ?   I am not sure about spain - if all you did was move them I think the 'engine' (motor) is fine. I think your capacitors are fine. I am thinking you have 230V Single Phase in spain .. So one hot and one neutral , maybe a ground. I am not sure what you measured (volts ohms ?) or where you measured. what switch a wall switch or on the fans themselves ?

Comment: You can go at local hardware store, buy a piece of electric cord (2 wires) and a plug, with that 'adaptor' you can easly try the fans on a standard outlet.

Picture of wires (both on the soffit and on the fan) will be helpful